# start roll out for production is disabled what is reasons?

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, google-play-services, google-play-console

start roll out for production is disabled what is reasons ? I am publishing app on google play but start production button is disabled even all query is checked with green mark and there is no warning ?
What is the issue ?